# How to create matrix columns from multiple files in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix

I have 3 txt files with the same number of rows. One txt contains date and time, and 2 txt files contains float numbers.
Is it possible to create a matrix or 2D array from that 3 files? I want the 1st file be the 1st column, the 2nd file be the 2nd column and the 3rd file be the 3rd column.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you can simply create a list of lists and put each line inside the correct internal list. You can do this as follow:

```
file1 = open("filename1.txt","r",encoding="utf-8" )
file2 = open("filename2.txt","r",encoding="utf-8" )
file3 = open("filename3.txt","r",encoding="utf-8" )
matrix = []
for line1 in file1:
    line1 = line1.strip()
    line2 = file2.readline().strip()
    line3 = file3.readline().strip()
    row = []
    row.append(line1) 
    row.append(line2)
    row.append(line3)
    matrix.append(row)


#Access the matrix:
print(matrix[0][0]) # first column - first row
print(matrix[0][1]) # second column - first row
print(matrix[0][2]) # third column - first row
```

Comment: Saved my life :D  Thank you so much. 

It seems quite simple and clear. Although I could have never done it like this on my own :/ 
Thanks!!!!